# Core Data - update UI after object in to-many relationship change property

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data model that look something like this:

```
Author
======
- name
- bio

- books (to-many relationship)


Book
====
- title
- release date

- author (to-one relationship)
```

I present to the user a table view of authors each table cell represent an author and shows his `name` and the `title` of the latest book he wrote.

To show the list of authors I use a `NSFetchedResultsController` with the following `NSFetchRequest` :

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Author"];
request.predicate = nil;
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
request.fetchBatchSize = 20;
```

**My question is:**

I let the user change the book title in another screen, and I want that if the user change the title of that latest book, the authors table view will update and reflect the recent change.

How can update that latest book title in my authors table view?

Answer (score 3):

If you already have NSFetchedResultController embed in your view controller with all delegation methods implemented (see the Duncan's answer posted earlier) then:

1. you subscribe your VC to context changes notification (in `viewDidLoad` or `init`)

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                            selector:@selector(contextUpdated:)                          
                                                name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                              object:nil];
   ```
2. implement the `contextUpdated` method

   ```
   -(void)contextUpdated:(NSNotification*)notification
   {
   // if the context changed on other screens
       NSManagedObjectContext *changedContext = notification.userInfo[@"managedObjectContext"];
       if ([changedContext isEqual: self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext]){
           [_tableView reloadData];
       }
   }
   ```
3. be sure you unsubscribe your VC from the notifications

   ```
   -(void)dealloc
   {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the fetchedResultsController delegate methods in your tableViewController and updates should be reflected in the tableView automatically.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
    atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
    atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                  atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I already implemented those delegates, the problem is that it won't work for this case cause my table view present authors, and the change is on the book object. if I had a books tableview than no problem the UI would be updated immediately, but here the delegate doesn't get called on the authors view controller when a book object changes.

Comment: If you are updating the latestBook attribute it should be called. See my other answer about adding such an attribute.

Comment: You may need to add an attribute latestBookName for the update to trigger a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

My **Solution**: add an boolean field named "triggerUpdate" to entity Author, other name and type are OK, too; if you update books write by the author, just set like this,

```
author.triggerUpdate = @(!author.triggerUpdate.boolValue);
```

The **reason** is that, any field of Author updating will trigger a notification of the type `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`.

By this way, I solved the problem. If you have better answer, please tell me.